# How to offload EF Core entity auditing to a different thread( Auditing should happen asynchronously without blocking actual entity savechanges)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm building an entity auditing solution using EF Core change tracking. I'm able to do it by overriding the SaveChangesAsync method and saving entity changes from the change tracker to an audit table before calling the context's save changes. This solution works fine, but it's adding overhead and performance issues as audit tracking needs to be performed before every SaveChangesAsync call. Is there a way to offload the change tracking and audit save to a separate thread? It should be in an asynchronous manner and the audit save should happen only if the actual save changes are committed to the database.

Comment: Maybe better to use Temporal Tables and let SQL Server to store changes automatically? And yes you can store audit data in separate context but what todo if  audit storing will fail?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, the temporal table is an option. But I'm looking for a centralized audit table for all of my entities. If we are using a separate context for audit, still we have to get the changes from the original context right?. I want to do it in a different thread asynchronously without blocking the actual flow.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception. There is an example which uses a SaveChanges interceptor for auditing.